# Really small font in AutoCAD table

Tags: c#, .net, autocad

I'm trying to make a table that dynamically adds rows as users submit more data:

```
public void addRow(String[] data)
{
Transaction tr = doc.TransactionManager.StartTransaction();
DocumentLock docLock = doc.LockDocument();
using (tr)
using (docLock)
{
if (!IsWriteEnabled || !IsReadEnabled) //Committing transactions closes everything for reading and writing so it must be reopened
{
tr.GetObject(this.ObjectId, OpenMode.ForRead);
tr.GetObject(this.ObjectId, OpenMode.ForWrite);
}
if (!data[0].Equals("Mark")) //If the data being added is not the titles of the columns
{
SetSize(NumRows + 1, NumColumns);
}

BlockTable bt = (BlockTable)tr.GetObject(doc.Database.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead);
BlockTableRecord btr = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(bt[Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices.BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace], OpenMode.ForWrite);
selectedRow = NumRows - 1; //Sets the lowest empty row as the one to be modified
//Adding data to each cell
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
Cells[selectedRow, i].SetValue(data[i], ParseOption.SetDefaultFormat);
}
GenerateLayout();
//Attempting to add table into drawing. If table already exists and is just being updated the catch statement will realize this and move on
try
{
btr.AppendEntity(this);
tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(this, true);
}
catch (Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.Exception e)
{
SetRowHeight(3); //Sets height of new row
SetColumnWidth(8); //Sets width of new columns
Cells.TextHeight = 1; //Sets height of new text
}

tr.Commit(); //Updating table
}
}
```

However what ends up happening is that the titles of the columns which are added when the table is created are formatted correctly (Center-aligned, good size font) but everything added after has really small font size. How do I make it so that the font size is the same with each entry added?

Comment: I think you should explicitly set the font formatting you want, just like you are setting row height and other properties.  Tables can be unpredictable.  For instance, just working in the AutoCAD UI, if you insert a row, it will often copy the formatting for color and font, but lose the number formatting.  If you want to be sure what it will do, be explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Turns out SetTextHeight's second parameter matters. The numbers 1-7 set different cells depending on their row type. To set the height of rows of type title, data, and header I needed to use

SetTextHeight(1, 7)